# TestCafe : How can I set the zoom level of browser while running tests in TestCafe

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I want to run my tests at zoom level less than 100% as few of the elements on some pages are not visible when I run tests.

Is there any way to set the zoom level of browser while running tests ?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your question. As of yet, TestCafe does not provide the functionality to set the zoom level on a page. I would suggest using a [Resize Window](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/basic-guides/interact-with-the-page.html#resize-window) if it's applicable to your scenario. Also, keep in mind that [Page Actions](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/basic-guides/interact-with-the-page.html) automatically scroll the target element into view. If these alternatives don't satisfy your needs, please keep track of the [zoom feature request](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/2314) in our GitHub repository.